# React - Material-UI Accordion: How to center header and expand icon

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently implementing the Accordion component of the Material-UI library in my react project:

**What I want to do is to have the accordion summary (header with "Accordion 1", "Accordion 2") centered and the expand icon (arrow) right below, also centered.**

In the Material-UI documentation (https://material-ui.com/components/accordion/), the displayed layout looks like the following:
[image]

With the following code (as shown in the documentation):

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
  },
}));

export default function SimpleAccordion() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Accordion 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
            sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel2a-content"
          id="panel2a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Accordion 2</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
            sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion disabled>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel3a-content"
          id="panel3a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Disabled Accordion</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing [flex-grow on the summary content](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/AccordionSummary/AccordionSummary.js#L44) from 1 to 0 appears to be sufficient:

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MuiAccordionSummary from "@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary";
const AccordionSummary = withStyles({
  content: {
    flexGrow: 0
  }
})(MuiAccordionSummary);
```

[image: Edit Centered AccordionSummary]

If you want the arrow centered underneath the summary text (instead of next to it as in my first example), then you can use the following:

```
const AccordionSummary = withStyles({
  root: {
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  content: {
    marginBottom: 0
  },
  expandIcon: {
    marginRight: 0,
    paddingTop: 0
  }
})(MuiAccordionSummary);
```

[image: Edit Centered AccordionSummary (forked)]

This second example also demonstrates using a class for SimpleAccordion (as requested in the comments) using `withStyles` instead of `makeStyles`/`useStyles` for the additional styling in the example.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Thanks a lot! Two things:
1. Is it possible to put the arrow in the middle of the bottom limiter, instead of next to the Header
2. I'm not using react hooks, but rather react classes. How would I change the style in the useStyles function: const useStyles = (theme) => ({....})

Comment: @MichelH. I've updated my answer to include a second example.